# @grapecity/wijmo throwing run time error after upgrading my Angular project from 8 to 9

Tags: angular9, wijmo, angular-ivy, angular-upgrade, grapecity

Recently iam trying to update my angular project from 8 to 9. While updating i also updated wijmo from wijmo/wijmo to @grapecity/wijmo package as it supports IVY.

But after the completing the upgradation, i can able to compile the application but i am getting the following error at run time

```
global-error-handler.service.ts:43 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: (0 , t[n]) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , t[n]) is not a function
    at backend.js:61
    at Reflect.<anonymous> (backend.js:61)
    at push../node_modules/@grapecity/wijmo.angular2.grid.detail/__ivy_ngcc__/index.js.__decorate (index.js:28)
    at index.js:53
    at Object../node_modules/@grapecity/wijmo.angular2.grid.detail/__ivy_ngcc__/index.js (index.js:53)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
```

Comment: Can you post exactly which version of wijmo you are using?

Comment: I am using "5.20202.732" version. If i change "enableIvy": false in tsconfig then it is working fine.  But if i opt to IVY i am getting the above error.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We are doing some investigating on our end. But if you have a repro sample it would help us debug this much more quickly. Feel free to reach out via email (see below).

Comment: One more question, are you inheriting our components? There are some breaking changes in decorators with Ivy and it could be one of those. I added some more explanation of those to the answer below. The topic I linked to is much more thorough too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to get some more info about this error. The quick thing to check is property initialization order. In Ivy, the properties are interpreted as they are specified in markup (previously wijmo controlled how they were interpreted). So you can break components by setting certain properties before others.

For example, if I tried to set the selectedIndex on a combobox BEFORE I set the data source, then the app would break at runtime because there are no items in the list to select yet.

More info here: https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/docs/GettingStarted/Angular-Components#property-initialization-order-in-angular-9-ivy-and-higher

The next thing to check is component decorators (if you are inheriting our components). There are some breaking changes in decorators in Ivy.

For example, you might need to add `{descendants: true}` to ContentChildren queries.

Or you might need to add an `@Injectable` decorator to your class.

You can read more about breaking changes in Ivy and how to fix them here: https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility-examples

But please feel free to contact us to work directly: wijmoexperts@grapecity.com